# Is it possible to change the default null character at the end of string

Tags: c, memory

I am studying strings and found that string ends with a null character - "\0". Is it possible to change this default null character by something else like "\1"?

I was performing the following code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    const char *str = "App\0le";

    printf("%c", *(str+5));
}
```

Comment: C-string are nul terminated. `std::string` might have `\0` in the middle.

Comment: Please don't put C and C++ tags on the same question. In almost all cases, it's wrong and, worse, it's cofusing: A solution for one language may not work (well) in the other. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `*(str+5)` might simply be `str[5]`.

Comment: Can you tell any reasonable use case, why one would do this?? @Anonymous

Comment: You can certainly change it: `char a[] = "foo";  a[3] = '\1';`, but after doing that `a` is no longer a string.  The definition of "string" is "an array of characters terminated by '\0'".    You are free to define "string" as "an array of characters terminated by '\1'", but you will have a difficult time convincing others to use that definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. You can use any sentinel in your char arrays but it will not be used in ***string literals***. You will have to write your own string functions (file too).

```
size_t mystrlen(const char *str)
{
    const char *end = str;
    while(*end != '\1') end++;
    return end - str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "12345\0006789\01";   // it will still append \0 to the end

    printf("%zu\n", mystrlen(str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings ending with `\0` is just a convention. They are called "null-terminated string". You can absolutely use another convention if you want, but you will have to write your own functions to work with it.

For example, the standard C function `puts` prints every character of the argument until it finds a `\0`, at which point it returns. `printf` works similarly when using the `%s` format specifier. You could write your own `my_puts` that prints every character of the argument until it finds a `\1`.

However, you won't be able to change the fact that string literals (like `"Apple"`) always end with `\0`. There might be other details like this where the standard uses null-terminated strings, but I can't think of more.